# Modal Muetras datos en Laravel 9 pero en 10 no

Tags: laravel, modal, livewire

tengo un formulario modal que muestra los estudiantes pertenecientes a una seccion (sistema de gestion escolar) funcionaba bien (mostraba los datos, hace un mes actualice el sistema  a laravel 10 y ahora al querer ver la informacion me muestra el modal y me dice que no hay informacion, anexo codigo

Codigo para llamar al modal

```
                                            <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#VerSeccionModal" wire:click="MostrarEstudiantes({{ $rs->id }})" class="buttonEst"></button>
```

Codigo del Controlador

```
public function MostrarEstudiantes($value)
{
    $ad = new secciones();
    $ad->setTable($this->nom_tabl_sec);
    $seccion1 = $ad->select('codigo','descseac')->where('id','=',$value)->first();
    $this->SecBus = $seccion1->codigo;
    $this->SecNom =  trim($seccion1->descseac);

    $aca = new academicos();
    $aca->setTable($this->nom_tabl_aca);
    $subquery = $aca->select('numalum', 'codalum', 'codsecc', 'id')->where('codsecc','=',$this->SecBus);
    
    $this->seccalum = Estudiante::joinSub($subquery, 'Academ', function ($join) {
        $join->on('estudiante.identa', '=', 'Academ.codalum');
    })->select('estudiante.*', 'Academ.numalum')
    ->orderby('estudiante.cedula')->get(10);

    //dd($this->SecBus);
}
```

Comment: el código no debiera retornar algo, aunque sea un string, para dibujar la respuesta?